# how to get array length in a doctrine query?

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

i'd like to know how to get the length of an array in a doctrine query? i use postgresql that has an array type and many functions to hundle arrays but i didn't find anything equivalent in doctrine, for instance i used:

```
SELECT a, abs(array_length(a.ssc,1)-array_length(a.ssb,1)) as d
FROM AbbPostBundle:Post a
order by d desc
```

but i got this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 17: Error: Expected known function, got 'array_length'o?
```

so i wonder what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [create custom DQL functions](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html) for vendor specific functions.